# Merge mixin external attributes width internally declared attributes without duplicating "class" key in Pug

Tags: pug

In below code, I need all of `InputField`, `InputField-TestClass` and `InputField-TestClass2` classes will be applied to root `div` in `CompoundControlBase` mixin:

```
mixin CompoundControlBase(propertiesObject)
  div&attributes({
    foo: someInternalAttribute
  }, attributes)
    // ...


mixin InputField(propertiesObject)

  const {
    CSS_Namespace
  } = propertiesObject

  +CompoundControlBase({
    // ...
  })&attributes({
    class: [
      CSS_Namespace,
      `${CSS_Namespace}-TestClass`,
    ]
  }, attributes)


+InputField({
  CSS_Namespace: "InputField"
}).InputField-TestClass2
```

I want to use `&attributes` literal to avoid attributes duplication like below (basically Pug can handle it, but sometimes could be the problem like linting warnings):

```
// Please, don't
+CompoundControlBase({
    // ...
  })(
    class= CSS_Namespace
    class=`${CSS_Namespace}-TestClass`
  )(attributes)
```

Unfortunately, Pug does not understand the spread operator:

```
+CompoundControlBase({
    // ...
  })&attributes({
    class: [
      CSS_Namespace,
      `${CSS_Namespace}__OneMoreClass`,
    ],
    ...attributes 
  })

// Error: Unexpected token (xxxx:xxxx)
```

Here, the `CSS_Namespace` and `${CSS_Namespace}-TestClass` will be ignored:

```
mixin InputField(propertiesObject)

  const {
    CSS_Namespace
  } = propertiesObject

  +CompoundControlBase({
    // ...
  })&attributes({
    class: [
      CSS_Namespace,
      `${CSS_Namespace}-TestClass`,
    ]
  }, attributes)
```

Comment: Have you tried `+CompoundControlBase({...})(class= CSS_Namespace + ' ' + CSSNamespace + '-TestClass')&attributes(attributes)`?

Comment: I'll try and remember it as option.

Comment: @Sean, It works! Thank you for the solution. Using ES6 template string, we can split classes declaration to multiple lines. Let's search for other alternatives. I'll start the bounty soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you should be able to rewrite the `InputField` mixin as follows:

```
mixin InputField(propertiesObject)

  - const { CSS_Namespace } = propertiesObject

  +CompoundControlBase({...})(class=`
      ${CSS_Namespace}
      ${CSS_Namespace}-TestClass
    `)&attributes(attributes)
```

If you want to more easily add multiple classes at this point, I'd suggest something like:

```
mixin InputField(args)
  -
    const { CSS_Namespace } = args
    const classesToNamespace = [
      'TestClass1',
      'TestClass2',
      'TestClass3'
    ]
    const classArray = classesToNamespace.map(name => `${CSS_Namespace}-${name}`)
    classArray.push(CSS_Namespace)

  +CompoundControlBase({...})(class=classArray)&attributes(attributes)
```